# mongoose not returning posts when *.find() is wrapped in a function

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

i have setup a simple express rest api and i want to get all posts when a certain route is requested from my rest server ("/api/posts")

i tried to `console.log(posts)` and it shows me the posts but when i try to go to the route http://localhost:5000/api/posts it shows me a blank page although console.logging the posts shows me the posts why is this

```
function getAllPosts() {
  Post.find((err, posts) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
    console.log(posts);
    console.log("all posts requested");
    return posts;
  });
}
router
  .route("/")
  .get((req, res) => {
    let posts = getAllPosts();
    res.send(posts);
  })
```

i expected to get the posts json when i go to http://localhost:5000/api/posts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you are returning value from the getAllpost functions, routes are getting undefined value because of async. Try to edit your code like this:

```
function getAllPosts(req, res) {
   Post.find((err, posts) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
    console.log(posts);
    console.log("all posts requested");
    res.send( { data: posts} );
  });
}
router
  .route("/").get((req, res) => {
     getAllPosts(req, res);

  });
```

Comment: thanks i was starting to pull my hair out where can i learn about asynchronous javascript strange unexpected things like this cost me 4 hours at a time do you know/recommend any decent sources for learning asynchronous javascript?

Comment: https://javascript.info/ i think this site is great, to learn about modern javascript including async . Also you can read articles and see tutorials and make small projects, hope then you will gradually  improve in js

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with the asynchronous nature of the code you have here. `res.send` is executing before `Post.find()` can resolve. You only want to `res.send(posts)` once the database query has finished fetching the data, if using callbacks, as you are in your example, you would do this inside of the callback. You could do something like this.

```
router
  .route("/")
  .get((req, res) => {
    Post.find({}, (err, posts) => {
       if (err) {
         return res.status(500).send(err)
       }

       res.send(posts)
    })
  })
```